# In Swift, how to get the y position of a text baseline of a UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilabel

I'm trying to get the exactly baseline of a text of a UILabel.

`label.frame.maxY` returns the max y of the **box** of the UILabel.

But what I really want is the maxY of the **position of the text**.

Ignore the "button". I just searched this image from google. I know how to get what the first returns (maxY), but I want to know how to get the second one (where the dashline is under the text).

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can achieve this using constraints - would that be ok for you, or do you need the actual value to calculate the frames yourself?

Comment: Try using `.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: Int.max, height: Int.max)` on the label, to get the label frame tighten up.

Comment: @Losiowaty I need to calculate the frames by myself

Comment: @DejanSkledar the height does not tighten up enought to get the exactly baseline

Comment: @DejanSkledar : also if you have letters like y/j/g/p in your text, they extend below baseline.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can achieve this quite simply :

```
let baselineY = label.frame.origin.y + label.font.ascender;
```